# Symfony2 - How to add a global parameter to routing for every request or generated URL similar to _locale?

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I try add global parameter

Parameter for all routes, and parameter setup in kernel Request Listener.

routing

```
mea_crm:
    resource: @Crm4Bundle/Resources/config/routing.yml
    prefix: /{_applicationid}
    defaults:  { _applicationid: 0 }
    requirements:
      _applicationid: |0|1|2|3|4|5|6
```

in Listener - `{ name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }`
I try setup this parameter

```
$request->attributes->add(array(
            '_applicationid'=>$appCurrentId
        ));
        $request->query->add(
            array(
                '_applicationid'=>$appCurrentId
            )
        );
$request->query->set('_applicationid',$appCurrentId);
```

and still have in routes - default value 0

Update 1 
i setup listener to max priority

```
tags:
     - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest, priority: 255 }
```

in listener setup

```
 public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {

        $event->getRequest()->request->set('_applicationid',1);

        return ;
```

and still don't have this parameter is routing.

UPDATE 2

its strange - i dump in Symfony\Component\Routing\Router

in method

```
public function matchRequest(Request $request)
....
var_dump($matcher->matchRequest($request));
        die();
```

and get

array (size=4)
  '_controller' => string 'Mea\TaskBundle\Controller\TaskListController::viewOneAction' (length=59)
  '_applicationid' => string '1' (length=1)
  'id' => string '700' (length=3)
  '_route' => string 'MeaTask_View' (length=12)

so there exist _applicationid

but in urls i dont have it

here is routing.yml

```
mea_crm:
    resource: @MeaCrm4Bundle/Resources/config/routing.yml
    prefix: /{_applicationid}
    defaults:  { _applicationid: null }
    requirements:
      _applicationid: |1|2|3|4|5|6
```

i have links like here: http://crm4.dev/app_dev.php//u/logs/list
any ideas ?

UPDATE 3

here is my listeners

```
php app/console debug:event-dispatcher kernel.request

Registered Listeners for "kernel.request" Event
===============================================

 ------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- 
  Order   Callable                                                                           Priority  
 ------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- 
  #1      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure()      2048      
  #2      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest()     1024      
  #3      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DumpListener::configure()               1024      
  #4      Mea\Crm4Bundle\Listener\CrmApplicationRequestListener::onKernelRequestInit()       255       
  #5      Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest()    128       
  #6      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest()     48        
  #7      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest()       32        
  #8      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest()       16        
  #9      FOS\RestBundle\EventListener\BodyListener::onKernelRequest()                       10        
  #10     Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest()   10        
  #11     Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest()                        8         
  #12     Mea\Crm4Bundle\Listener\CrmApplicationRequestListener::onKernelRequest()           0         
  #13     Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest()      0         
 ------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
```

in CrmApplicationRequestListener :: onKernelRequestInit

i setup onKernelRequestInit and it is visible now.

But still i need change in routing  defaults:  { _applicationid: 0 }

every path generated by symfony have default _applicationid: 0 not current real _applicationid set in listener. 
Add current _applicationid for every routing is not possible. I must change default in router. I have hope that problem is clear now.

UPDATE 4
I also try to create custom routing loader - here is question 
[symfony2 add dynamic parameter for routing, try with custom loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36237070/symfony2-add-dynamic-parameter-for-routing-try-with-custom-loader)

Comment: When defining the router parameter in the routing.yml it is automatically added to the request query parameters already.Why do you want to add it to the attributes?

Comment: you want **every** route in your application to have/allow this prefix without putting every route configuration into one `resource` ?

Comment: Yes i want _applicationid in all routes. I have var in Kernel request listener but cannot find how to setup it - i push $request->query->set('_applicationid',$appCurrentId); - but still have in routes  _applicationid = 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem isn't very clear, but you might want to check your listener priority is set so that it runs before the router listener.

---

EDIT:

Assuming you're not trying to set the value of `_applicationid` in your twig view using `path()` – e.g. `{{ path('path_name', {'_applicationid': 2}) }}` – which will work, and may be the better option – you should still be able to set it using a listener.

After examining Symfony's own `LocaleListener`, I was able to set the value of `_applicationid` to `2` with the statement `$this->router->getContext()->setParameter('_applicationid', 2);`. The priority of the subscriber doesn't seem to make any difference, but setting the value in the view takes precedence over the listener.

Framework routing:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
acme_test:
    resource: "@AcmeTestBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_applicationid}
    defaults:
        _applicationid: 0
    requirements:
        _applicationid: 0|1|2|3|4
```

Bundle Routing:

```
# src/Acme/TestBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml
acme_test_home:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeTestBundle:Default:index }
```

Service definition:

```
# src/Acme/TestBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    acme_test.listener.app_id_listener:
        class: Acme\TestBundle\EventListener\AppIdListener
        arguments:
            - "@router"
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Subscriber:

```
# src/Acme/TestBundle/EventListener/AppIdListener.php
namespace Acme\TestBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class AppIdListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct($router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $this->router->getContext()->setParameter('_applicationid', 2);
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 15)),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: i do it but still parameter not exist in router

Comment: Have you debugged the listener priority in the console? I found recently that I couldn't set the priority on a listener, it always ended at 0. I had to make it a subscriber instead, then I was able to set the priority.

Comment: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener have KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 32)), = priority 32 so if i use 255 my listener run first and run. I see this parameter in request (in symfony default Router Listener) but it is not used in routing. I dont have ide why

Comment: Yes, but try running `php app/console debug:event-dispatcher kernel.request` in your cli. It will show you the actual priority that Symfony has given your listener. Is it still 255?

Comment: yes it have 255 and its run i think ok. I update example please see

Comment: Strange. I don't think you should have to make `onKernelRequestInit`; `onKernelRequest` should be enough. Anyway, I see that you're passing a string as `_applicationid` value. Shouldn't that be an integer?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is by overriding symfony's default `router` service.

You can find an example how to override the default router in the [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle).

Take a look at [I18nRouter](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/blob/master/Router/I18nRouter.php) and [SetRouterPass](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Compiler/SetRouterPass.php)

---

The alternative would be adding a custom route-loader that adds all the prefixed routes.

You can find examples for this in the documentation chapter [**How to Create a Custom Route Loader**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html)

Comment: is not easy way, first i try any other ways. I just want add one parameter to route maybe concept with get request before router do it is possible

Comment: Hi i try use custom loader but, please look - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36237070/symfony2-add-dynamic-parameter-for-routing-try-with-custom-loader